# Modify longest palindromic substring condition with specific input.?

Tags: java, string, algorithm, palindrome

I was trying to find the algo for finding the longest palindromic substring problem.

However, my algo is failing few testcases.

```
public static String longestPalindrome2(String s) {
        String maxPal  = "";
        if (s == null || s.length() < 1) return "";
        String rev = new StringBuilder(s).reverse().toString();
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            for (int j = i; j < s.length(); j++) {
                String temp = s.substring(i, j);
                if(rev.contains(temp) ) {
                    if(temp.length() > maxPal.length()) {
                        maxPal = temp;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return maxPal;
    }
```

When I pass "abacdgfdcaba" since the "abacd" is present 2 times in differnet parts of string and because of this reason it fails.

How can i change my condition so that i can pass this type of testcases ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why does one shouldn't speak when they don't know the problem?

Comment: In your inner loop, it is only worth looking for substrings which are longer than the longest a palidrome, no need to start at 1.

Comment: I assume you are looking for the longest substring which is a palindrome, not the longest string which is present in the reverse of the whole string.

Comment: In which case you should start with  length of the whole string, and get shorter until you find a palindrome and stop.

Comment: @Peter that' right. I was going thru 1st solution  https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-palindromic-substring/solution/ and i need to make a check  We could see that the longest common substring method fails when there exists a reversed copy of a non-palindromic substring in some other part of SS. Here they say "To rectify this, each time we find a longest common substring candidate, we check **if the substring’s indices are the same as the reversed substring’s original indices.**"

Comment: @nicky that is needlessly complicated. Can you confirm what the requirement is?

Answer (score 1):

You are not checking if the `String` is a palindrome when you search for `temp` in `rev`.

```
private static boolean isPalindrome(String s) {
    String rev = new StringBuilder(s).reverse().toString();
    return s.equals(rev);
}
```

Add this method and check it before assigning `maxPal = temp` value.